# Error: Invalid bytes6 value

Tags: solidity, remix, error, bytes, encoding

I'm trying to create a TicketPurchaser application. Here is the whole code for the smart contract, although I think the problem I'm asking about is a type error, most of the code is not important.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;



/** @title TicketPurchaser
    @dev Let's the user buy ticket for event, which can be validated by gatekeeper at the event.
    @author imestin
 */
contract TicketPurchaser {
    mapping (bytes6 => address) tickets;                        //One address can buy multiple tickets, so the ticket is the key. 
    mapping (bytes6 => bool) expired;                           //True if ticket is already claimed 
    uint TicketPrice;                                           //Ticket price in wei

    //User can buy a ticket using ether
    function BuyTicket() public payable returns (string) {
        //If this condition is not true, program will exit.
        require(msg.value >= TicketPrice);
        if (msg.value > TicketPrice) {
            msg.sender.transfer(msg.value-TicketPrice);
        }

        SaveCode(GenerateSixDigitCode());
    }

    function GenerateSixDigitCode() private view returns (bytes6) {
//        uint8[6] memory AlphaIndex;                     //We add up 2 hex digit, than multiply it by 1.125 (32 to 36 conversion)
//        string memory AlphaNumerics = new string(36);
//        AlphaNumerics = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
//        bytes6 SixDigit;

        //This is not really good, "seed" will be sha256 hash, and we want. 6-digit.
//        bytes32 seed = (keccak256(abi.encodePacked(
//            block.timestamp + block.difficulty +
//            ((uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.coinbase)))) / (now)) +
//            block.gaslimit + 
//            ((uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender)))) / (now)) +
//            block.number
//        )));

        //This is the string that we are getting the index for: "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
//        AlphaIndex[0] = ToAlphaIndex(seed[0], seed[1]);
//        AlphaIndex[1] = ToAlphaIndex(seed[0], seed[1]);
//        AlphaIndex[2] = ToAlphaIndex(seed[0], seed[1]);
//        AlphaIndex[3] = ToAlphaIndex(seed[0], seed[1]);
//        AlphaIndex[4] = ToAlphaIndex(seed[0], seed[1]);
//        AlphaIndex[5] = ToAlphaIndex(seed[0], seed[1]);

        //Let's suppose AlphaIndex worked. 
  /*      SixDigit[0] = AlphaNumerics[AlphaIndex[0]];
        SixDigit[1] = AlphaNumerics[AlphaIndex[1]];
        SixDigit[2] = AlphaNumerics[AlphaIndex[2]];
        SixDigit[3] = AlphaNumerics[AlphaIndex[3]];
        SixDigit[4] = AlphaNumerics[AlphaIndex[4]];
        SixDigit[5] = AlphaNumerics[AlphaIndex[5]];*/

        SixDigit = "X4C9BA";
        return SixDigit;
    }

    //The returning value 
    function ToAlphaIndex(bytes1 x, bytes1 y) private pure returns (uint8) {
        return uint8((uint16(x) + uint16(y)) * 9 / 8);
    }

    //we could simple continou coding this and simulating the 6-digit-generation. This way we could have a working contract
    function SaveCode(bytes6 SixDigit) private {
        // will alter tickets mapping
        // should check if 6-digit-code is alpha-numeric, return true or ERR
        //we don't care about this right now
        tickets[SixDigit] = msg.sender;
    }

    //Gatekeeper can validate the ticket of the user
    //This will alter state, because it is invalidating a ticket.
    function RedeemTicket(bytes6 SixDigit) public payable returns (bool) {
        //User will present 6-digit-code (probalby written down in piece of paper.)

        //Gatekeeper prompts the code. It doesn't really matter who owns the code (you can buy tiket for another person). 
        //The thing that matters, that tickets[code] > 0
        require(tickets[SixDigit] > 0);


        //If tickets[code] > 0, we still need to check that the ticket hasn't been already claimed.
        //If this is true, we set expired[code] = true
        if ( !expired[SixDigit] ) {
            expired[SixDigit] = true;
            return true;
            //Green light "Success!"
        } else {
            return false;                   
            //Already claimed!
        }
    }
}
```

I'm testing it in Remix.
It's obvious that Six-Digit-generation is not working. What I would like to solve right now, is that I'm sending in a fix string ("X4C9BA"), and it will save it, and I will be able to redeem the ticket. (calling RedeemTicket will invalidate the ticket.)
I think saving the code works, I checked with "Debug" button, this is in the tickets mapping:

```
tickets: mapping(bytes6 => address)

     5834433942410000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000: 0xCA35B7D915458EF540ADE6068DFE2F44E8FA733C
```

I assume this is the hex representation of "X4C9BA", but I don't truly understand to be honest, what is 5834433942410000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.

But When I send in "X4C9BA" to RedeemTicket, it gives error.

```
transact to TicketPurchaser.RedeemTicket errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid bytes6 value (arg="", coderType="bytes6", value="X4C9BA", version=4.0.44)
```

How to fixthis type error?
Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the hexadecimal representation of the 6-byte value that you want to pass.

First off, it should start with `0x` (although Remix might be able to manage without it).

But more importantly, it needs to consist of 12 hexadecimal characters, since each character represents 4 bits, while each byte stores 8 bits (so each byte is represented by 2 characters).

Assuming what you want is **the string** `"X4C9BA"`, you should find the ASCII code of each character in that string, then convert this code into hexadecimal base, then replace each character with the corresponding result.

Here is a [tool](https://www.browserling.com/tools/text-to-ascii) which does it all for you, and it seems that you should use `0x885267576665`.

Comment: thank you! it worked!
It requires leading '0x'

Comment: @Imestin: You're welcome, I added the outcome in that tool.